# Produce a range of '..' separated numbers

Tags: python

I would like a string like `0..1..2..3..4`

So far what I have come up with is `a = list(range(5))`, however I need it to output in the format of `'#,#,#,#'`

so I thought oh this is just a string format so I just did `a = str(list(range(5)))`, but this just makes a `[#,#,#,#]` a string.

Im not sure if I am just missing a simple function, or if using `range` is the correct function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can join a list of number strings.

```
>>> "..".join(map(str, range(5)))
'0..1..2..3..4'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
print('..'.join(str(i) for i in range(a)))
```

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be two questions here:

1- To reproduce what's on the question's body, you can use join with list multiplication:

```
a = ','.join(['#']*5)
print(a)
```

Output:

```
#,#,#,#,#
```

2- To reproduce what's on the question's title, use:

```
a = '..'.join(str(i) for i in range(5))
print(a)
```

Output:

```
0..1..2..3..4
```